# Add values one by one to the table in sql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert values one by one after checking that it is valid and not empty, after submit, I want to display a message confirming that my registration has been created but it give me Error: INSERT INTO subscribers (comment,reg_date) VALUES (",CURRENT_TIME()) .

Create Table subscribers

```
"CREATE TABLE subscribers (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Insert Data Into MySQL table

```
if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (name)
VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."')";   
}
if(!empty($_POST["lastname"]) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (lastname)
VALUES ('".$_POST["lastname"]."')";   
}
if(!empty($_POST["email"]) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (email)
VALUES ('".$_POST["email"]."')";   
}
if(!empty($_POST["gender"])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (gender)
VALUES ('".$_POST["gender"]."')";   
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (comment,reg_date)
VALUES ('".$_POST["comment"]."',CURRENT_TIME())";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: Please give the *complete* error message

Comment: Each `INSERT` creates a new row. Don't you want these all to be fields in the same row?

Comment: Each `if` statement is overwriting `$sql`. Then you overwrite all of that with the unconditional `INSERT INTO subscribers(comment, reg_date)...` at the end. So that's the only query that will be executed.

Comment: yes i want these all to be fields in the same row after checking that is not empty or not valid,how can i do it.

Comment: Please provide the data definition of the table and sanitize the user input

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a single query that inserts all the columns, not separate queries for each column. And you should use a prepared statement rather than concatenating variables.

The input validation should report an error, not assign queries.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$_POST['name'])) {
    die("Invalid name"); 
}
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['lastname'])) {
    die("Invalid last name");  
}
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Invalid email");
}
if(empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    die("Empty gender"); 
}

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO subscribers (name, lastname, email, gender, comment, reg_date) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIME())";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['comment']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $stmt->error;
}
```